# Is this a nonessential phrase / is this comma usage correct?

Tags: commas

A coworker was writing an email and two other coworkers reviewed it. The phrase in question was something like:

> Please see the following attached file, showing our hours spent on projects from date A through date B.

They were arguing over whether that comma makes sense and I just wanted to see if someone could explain why it is or isn’t correct. I lean towards it being incorrect but can’t justify why.

Comment: IMO it's ambiguous. You could pause after "file" to show that you're providing non-essential additional information, or you could say it without a pause to tell people which attached file to look at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part after the comma—"showing our hours spent on projects from date A through date B"—is a participial phrase. It functions as an adjective that modifies "file" (or more specifically, "attached file"). The comma is not necessary.

Comment: Is the comma not necessary because the participial phrase is neither at the beginning of the sentence nor itself a complete sentence? (This is the rule I’ve heard about commas with participial phrase).